# How do i correctly implement web scraping into my api

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm making a django api that is able to return a definition of a word to a user this word is looked up by using a word=(put word here) url, this api scrapes dictionary.com to get the definition if it does not already exist inside my database, than adds it to my database if it exists on their site. i'm just trying to figure out how to actually structure it correctly instead of just throwing it into my view. I want to be able to return json to the end user with suggestions if a word is not found in the database or on their websites by scraping their recommendations.

I have tried returning json responses inside the view if a 404 error happens. Always throws a error i'm under the assumption my whole structure is wrong.

```
# the queryset for a view
def get_queryset(self):
    # this gets the word put into the url
    word = self.kwargs['word']
    headers = {"User-Agent": "user agent stuff"}
    # this checks if it exists in the database
    if not Word.objects.filter(word=word).exists():
        #this is the web scraping
        page = requests.get(f"https://www.dictionary.com/browse/{word}?s=t", headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        try:
            output = soup.find("div",{"value": "1"}).get_text()
            # this saves the web scraped info to the database
            test = Word(word=self.kwargs['word'].strip(), meaning=output)
            test.save()
        except:
            return
    # this returns the word and definition
    return Word.objects.all()
```

i expect the user to be able to get a definition if the word exists or if it doesn't to be able to return recommendations that i web scrape for them to choose from.

Comment: Are you able to save the scraped the data from dictionary.com into the database.?

Comment: @AlbinAntony I absolutely am it all works just fine, except for returning data when the word doesn't exist on dictonary.com.

Comment: If the word is not found what do you expect to return back.?

Comment: @AlbinAntony i want to than be able to scrap dictionary.com at its 404 page to get the words it thinks might be similar to what you are looking for and then return them as json

Comment: Sorry didn't get you clearly. If the word is not found in the db then you want to scrape dictionary.com, if the word is also not found in dictionary.com, then what you want to do?

Comment: @AlbinAntony If the word is also not found on dictionary.com i want to scrap the 404 page that it gave me for its recommended words aka the words it thinks you may have been looking for and than send like 3 of those off as json to the end user

Comment: So if I search "parentsw" then the page shows me suggestions like "
parentese
parent's
parentis
parenties
parenty's
parens
parent
parenties'
prints
prunts
parens'
parens.
parenty
prints'
prunts'
print's
prunt's
parens's". You want return 3 values from this right.?

Answer (score 0):

get_queryset is probably not the right place to put your scraping logic. Instead you want to use the default query set for your model to see if you have a definition, if not then perform the query to the 3rd party api, store the response into your database and return the definition to the user.

Outline

```
class WordViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Word.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WordSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        word = Word.objects.find(id=pk)
        if not word:
            # query 3rd party api
            res = requests.get('dictionary.com', params={'q': request.param['word']})
            word = res.json()['definition']
            word = Word('title': ..., 'definition': ...)
            word.save()
        serializer = WordSerializer(word)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I found that doing what you said but then defining get instead of get_queryset allowed me to Use Response to now return whatever Json i want

Comment: typically if you want to customize the Json response you'll want to customize the serializer. It is common in drf to define many serializers even for a single model.

Comment: Perfect! Ill give that a try. Im still trying to understand serializers as this is my first time working with them.